# Can I get editors in natbib under bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I use natbib under bibtex. If I want to reference an article in a collection I get the template

```
@InCollection{ID,
author = {author},
title = {title},
booktitle = {booktitle},
OPTcrossref = {crossref},
OPTkey = {key},
OPTpages = {pages},
OPTpublisher = {publisher},
OPTyear = {year},
OPTeditor = {editor},
OPTvolume = {volume},
OPTnumber = {number},
OPTseries = {series},
OPTtype = {type},
OPTchapter = {chapter},
OPTaddress = {address},
OPTedition = {edition},
OPTmonth = {month},
OPTnote = {note},
OPTannote = {annote},
}
```

and a corresponding output when filed in. But often there are several editors of a volume. How can I get a modified template that allows me to reference several editors?

Comment: Do you mean something like `editor={Editor1 and Editor2 and Editor3}`?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. Does it suffice to use "and" as separator?

Comment: Yes, you can use "and" to concatenate editors like you do with authors.

Comment: But I want the bibliographic item to then correctly withe "editors" and not simply "editor".

It is not useful to have a bibliographic item write: Peter Jones and Mary Smith and Oliver Jobs, editor.

Comment: Please see my answer. You get "editors" if there are more than one ...

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal It allows the `filecontents` environment to overwrite `\jobname.bib`. Normally, the engine would refuse to overwrite an existing file. The purpose of the `filecontents` environment is just so that the `.bib` and `.tex` file can be combined into a single `.tex` file. You are unlikely to want to use this mechanism in your actual document.

Comment: So do I need to add the filecontents package in the preamble of my document?

Comment: So my ref.bib file remains unchanged - except for the use of "and" as separator in editor{} - and also my text.tex fil remains unchanged?

Comment: I now tried to use your preamble 

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[%
  newcommands     % \RaggedRight=\raggedright etc. 
 ,newparameters   % use default settings of ragged2e
]{ragged2e}
%\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}  % to visualise the typing area and margins
\usepackage{hyperref}

but that did not cut it for me.

Comment: I have become confused and am calling for some assistance. Please bear with me. I will accept your answer when I learn how to get my head around it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@book{test,
  editor    = {First Editor and Second Editor2 and Third Editor3},
  title     = {Test to show the effect},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  year      = {2015},
  ISBN      = {0-0000-000000-0},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[%
  newcommands     % \RaggedRight=\raggedright etc. 
 ,newparameters   % use default settings of ragged2e
]{ragged2e}
%\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}  % to visualise the typing area and margins
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
{\raggedright  % group to end left justification after bib
\bibliography{\jobname}
}              % ends group for left justified bibliography

\end{document}
```

In book "Test" you see the line `editor  = {First Editor and Second Editor2 and Third Editor3},`.  The result is:

[image]

See entry 3 of the bibliography.